# Fail to set static file (image) as background with css

Tags: css, django, jinja2

I have this code.

`<div class="g-fullheight--xs g-bg-position--center swiper-slide" style="background:{% static'/img/1920x1080/02.jpg' %}">`

but it's doesn't work: no background is set but the url seems fine, no http errors.

how to add path in style. As correct using Jinja

The origin code is

```
<div class="g-fullheight--xs g-bg-position--center swiper-slide" style="background: url('img/1920x1080/01.jpg');">
```

---

## Solved

Solution

```
<div class="g-fullheight--xs g-bg-position--center swiper-slide" style="background: url({% static '/img/1920x1080/02.jpg' %})">
```

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work" means!

Comment: @KlausD. It can't load the file.

Comment: What url is finally present on page? Which http response do you get when trying to open it directly manually? 404?

Comment: @IvanStarostin it's no error. but the file doesn't show. I don't understand too. just want to bring image into style. The whole project i used jinja. For call the file from path. Then present it into webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

original code:

```
style="background: url('img/1920x1080/01.jpg');">
```

jinja code:

```
style="background:{% static'/img/1920x1080/02.jpg' %}
```

which would result in:

```
style="background: /my/static/img/1920x1080/02.jpg"
```

see the difference between this code and the original one? `url('')` is missing.

Comment: This work `<div class="g-fullheight--xs g-bg-position--center swiper-slide" style="background: url({% static '/img/1920x1080/02.jpg' %})">`